# Having problems with links in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, wkwebview

I tried making an app using WKWebView. I have a website which displays a catalog with multiple pages and items, and each item has a link attached to it. Each link takes you to a section of a website, but before accessing the website, the user needs to login.
Website: https://draghi-dot.github.io/draghi.github.io/

How can I make the links work? I do have to specify that I do not have a licensed Apple developer account. Does that make a difference?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)

        if let url = URL(string: "https://draghi-dot.github.io/draghi.github.io/") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            
            // Add cookies to the request
            if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
                let headers = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies)
                request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            }
            
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        webView.frame = view.bounds
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }

        // Check if the host is the sign-in page
        
        // Check if the link is an internal link (same host)
        if let host = url.host, host == "shop.prosol.ca" {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }

        // Open external links in device browser
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Save cookies after successful navigation
        if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: webView.url!) {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: webView.url, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried handling cookies but did not work.